# Join two data frames with multiple keys

Tags: join, apache-spark, dataframe, pyspark, rdd

I have two data frames one with id and random values, and a second one with tuple of id and a value.
I'd like to replace the tuple of id by their corresponding random values i've generated in the first dataframe. 
I coded it but the results are not good.

Example

```
id2word=sc.parallelize([(1),(2),(3)])

def build_data(j):
  a=random.uniform(-0.5,0.5)
  return (j,a)

rdd1 = id2word.map(build_data).toDF(['id_word','value'])

+-------+-------------------+
|id_word|              value|
+-------+-------------------+
|      1| 0.4651491097313888|
|      2|0.32978333933864534|
|      3|0.32978333933864534|
+-------+-------------------+

rdd2 = sc.parallelize([(1,2,1), (1,3, 0), (2,3,1)]).toDF(['id_main','id_context','coocur'])

+-------+----------+------+
|id_main|id_context|coocur|
+-------+----------+------+
|      1|         2|     1|
|      1|         3|     0|
|      2|         3|     1|
+-------+----------+------+
```

The goal is to replace the id_main value and id_context value by their id_word value defined in rdd1.
I used a join in order to achieve it but the results are not coherent at all. I don't understand why

```
df=rdd1.join(rdd2,rdd1.id_word==rdd2.id_main).select(rdd2.id_context,rdd1.value,rdd2.coocur)
df2=rdd1.join(df,df.id_context==rdd1.id_word)
```

This is my results and there are not good because for coocur 0 i should get value of id_word = 1 (0.4651491097313888) and id_word = 3 (0.32978333933864534) instead i have 0.32978333933864534 and 0.32978333933864534

```
+-------------------+-------------------+------+
|              value|              value|coocur|
+-------------------+-------------------+------+
|0.32978333933864534|0.32978333933864534|     0|
|0.32978333933864534|0.32978333933864534|     1|
| 0.4651491097313888| 0.4651491097313888|     1|
+-------------------+-------------------+------+
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are pulling the same column "value" twice . to be safe I have aliased the value column appropriate with "id_main" and "id_context" and they are working as expected.

```
>>> def build_data(j):
...    import random
...    a=random.uniform(-0.5,0.5)
...    return (j,a)
...
>>> rdd1 = sc.parallelize(map(lambda x: build_data(x) ,range(1,4))).toDF(['id_word','value'])
>>> rdd2 = sc.parallelize([(1,2,1), (1,3, 0), (2,3,1)]).toDF(['id_main','id_context','coocur'])
>>> temp = rdd2.join(rdd1, rdd2.id_main == rdd1.id_word).select(rdd1.value.alias('id_main'),rdd2.id_context,rdd2.coocur)
>>> result = temp.join(rdd1, temp.id_context == rdd1.id_word).select(temp.id_main, rdd1.value.alias('id_context'), rdd2.coocur)

>>> rdd1.show()
+-------+--------------------+
|id_word|               value|
+-------+--------------------+
|      1| 0.14148875937228922|
|      2| 0.22399596259278198|
|      3|-0.10276714457192437|
+-------+--------------------+

>>> result.show()
+-------------------+--------------------+------+
|            id_main|          id_context|coocur|
+-------------------+--------------------+------+
|0.14148875937228922|-0.10276714457192437|     0|
|0.22399596259278198|-0.10276714457192437|     1|
|0.14148875937228922| 0.22399596259278198|     1|
+-------------------+--------------------+------+
```

Comment: I know but when I used a random function to generate the value it doesn't work.

Comment: can you update the question with the result you are getting.. ?

Comment: @samymustek I have updated my results to use your `build_data` function. I am getting expected results. can you eloborate what you mean by incoherent result ?

Comment: can you please post the result you are getting in your question ? and explain what do you mean by "not good"

Comment: The last dataframe is my results and you can see that it doesn't match but look like you solved the problem in your code

Comment: I think you are pulling the same column "value" twice . to be safe I have aliased the value column appropriate with "id_main" and "id_context". so my guess is that proper aliasing will avoid this error.

Comment: Yes rogue it's working great idea with the alias thanks

Comment: Does the code works as well when remove '.alias('id_main')'? There is some error when I try that way